# I'm new to Java and I keep seeing "unused import" every time I try to import the Scanner class. What does unused import mean?

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-warnings

UPDATE: Thanks for all the help friends. I realized that it was simple. I wasn't using the Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in); statement. The alert disappeared after I completed the code.

I'm trying to get used to Java and Netbeans before the new semester starts. I've been following this website (https://www.codesdope.com/java-input-by-user/) just to try things out as a beginner. Whenever I use the `import java.util.Scanner` statement, I keep getting an unused import alert. Could anybody tell me how I can avoid this and what's causing the alert?

Sorry, I didn’t really have much code besides the template and the import. Here it is for better reference.

```
package codesdope;

import java.util.Scanner;  //This is where the unused import alert comes up

public class CodesDope
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your imports?

Comment: Sounds like you're not using `Scanner` in your code, so the `import` is pointless and Java is letting you know it.

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with code you're not showing us.  All we can tell you is that you're importing something that you're not using, or perhaps is covered by a duplicate import.  Don't just link the tutorial you may or may not be following, show the actual problem.

Comment: You have to make an instance of the scanners class.
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)

Comment: It is just a hint from your IDE that the import currently is not necessary. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: No reason to excuse that you have little code, on the contrary. The ideal is [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and I should say that you are giving us exactly that.

Comment: Import java.util.Scanner; tells the compiler to load this library in memory while running this program. In order to use the library, you have to create objects. It is just a warning from an intelligent compiler guiding the developers to remove unnecessary packages that are not being used. In this case you are only including the package but not using it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your given link, seems like you are importing both `import java.util.*;` and `import java.util.Scanner;`

If you are using `import java.util.*;` you don't need to put `import java.util.Scanner;` again since the first one import all things inside `util` package including `Scanner`. That's might be the reason.

Anyway in your scenario use `import java.util.Scanner;` only without importing every thing in `util` package since you are not using the other things in `util` package

According to your updated code, you are not using the `Scanner` in anywhere in your code. I mean you are not creating a Scanner object in your code. So as it says the `Scanner` import is unused. If you are not going to create a one you can remove the import. If you are hoping to create a one you will not get that error after you create a `Scanner` object in your code.

Comment: Yes, I used just the "import java.util.Scanner;"

Comment: @ApoorvJoshi I have updated my answer. Please refer the last part

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the given [link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_EditorUsersGuide#How_to_get_rid_of_unused_imports), it seems you have imported the package but not using that imported stuffs in your code.

After looking into your code snippet, you have imported `import java.util.Scanner;` but you are not using it since getting `unused import` warning.